# Locate an element by partial fill attribute Selenium/ C#

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

I want to locate all the path elements that contain partial fill attribute '#7cb5ec'

How to express this in Xpath?

```
<path fill="#7cb5ec" d="M 1015 130.02026666666666 C 1020.328 130.02026666666666 1020.328 138.02026666666666 1015 138.02026666666666 C 1009.672 138.02026666666666 1009.672 130.02026666666666 1015 130.02026666666666 Z"></path>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select the path with a partial CSS Selctor where fill contains #7cb5ec:

```
var element = driver.FindElementByCssSelector("path[fill*='#7cb5ec']")
```

And with an XPath:

```
var element = driver.FindElementByXPath("//path[contains(@fill,'#7cb5ec')]")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the XPath as below also

```
driver.FindElementByXPath("//path[@fill='#7cb5ec']");
```

Hope it will help you :)